# How to filter some special field in JSON?

Tags: java, json

I want to skip some special in my JSON parsing.
Fake code:

```
class A {
    String name;
    Boolean isOk;
}
```

My instance:

```
A a1 = new A("fake1", true);  
A a2 = new A("nobody", false);
```

When name is "nobody", parsing would skip this field.

So my expecting json is:

> a1 -> {"name":"fake1","isOk":"true"}
>   a2 -> {"isOk":"false"}

I know there is a way to solve this by writing `TypeAdapter` or `JsonSerializer`.
Is there any other implements in a more generic way?

Answer (score 1):

Jackson will use getter methods by default to get values. It's far more straightforward to do that in the getter that in a custom serializer:

```
String getName() {
    return "nobody".equals(name) ? null : name;
}
```

If you can't modify the getter you can make another one just for Jackson:

```
@JsonProperty("name")
String getNameUnlessNobody() {
    return "nobody".equals(name) ? null : name;
}

// tell jackson to ignore standard getter
@JsonIgnore
String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

Not quite as straightforward though.

Comment: This is quit elegant. Thanks so much. One more question, can I customize an object mapper or a gson builder and how? Getter method would be used in other place, which may be unsafe.